# Making AJAX requests in Rails without a form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I have a `posts` scaffold generated in a Rails app and I've added an `upvote` and `downvote` column to the post model. I added an "upvote" button on the view file and I need to make an AJAX call and query the database when you hit the upvote button, but the upvote button has no real Rails `<form>` attached to it. How can I make this AJAX call and add the upvote to the database for the upvoted post?

When I make this AJAX call:

```
$('.up,.down').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/posts',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {
        post: {
          upvote: 1
        }
      },
      success: function(){
        alert('success')
      }
    });
  });
```

It returns a 500 error. Where do I go form here?

Comment: there are two things to look at. 1) what request is actually sent (use chrome dev tools, look at network. 2) what does rails receive? it sounds like you hit a 500 in rails. check the development.log. see what `params` it received.

Comment: `Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-09 16:55:16 -0800
Processing by PostsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"post"=>{"upvote"=>"1"}}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms`

Comment: ah. so its the CSRF token you need. in your `application.html` make sure you have `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`. the `jquery-rails` integration should append this meta field into the headers.

Comment: Added it! Thank you! But my AJAX call is adding a new row and giving it one upvote. How do I modify my AJAX call to UPDATE the post I clicked?

Comment: that's a different problem. I suggest you post a question showing your controller / model code.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I'm going to pursue pferdefleisch's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `:remote => true` attribute on the `link_to` helper
for example:

```
<%= link_to post_upvote_path(post), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>
<%= link_to post_downvote_path(post), :remote => true, :method => "put" %>
```

then in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :posts do
  put "upvote", :to => "posts#upvote", as: :upvote
  put "downvote", :to => "posts#downvote", as: :downvote
end
```

then handle the voting in your posts controller, like you probably already are and grab the post id with `params[:id]` in the action

[Here is an intro to rails flavored unobtrusive javascript](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/)

**Update**
To see the upvote and downvote routes that were created, go to the terminal and type

```
rake routes | grep vote
```

this will give you a list of all of your routes that have "vote" in the name. Or just type `rake routes` to get a list of all of them. The first column is the named route, just append '_path' to the end of it to use it in your app - like `post_upvote_path` above would be seen as

```
post_upvote  PUT  /posts/:id/upvote(.:format) posts#upvote
```

And in you PostsController you would want these actions:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ###
  # index, show... other RESTful actions here
  ###


  def upvote
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    # code for however you are voting up the post here
  end

  def downvote
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
    # code for however you are voting down the post here
  end
end
```

Comment: Where would I create post_upvote_path(post)? The controller? What should it look like? Is this method better than having a $.AJAX() request in the application.js file?

Comment: I added more examples. This is the more "Rails Way" of doing it but I often use `$.ajax()` in certain situations. I'd say go with something like this and if it gives you pain, try something else.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! One last question, you say "then in your routes..." do you mean routes.rb file?

Comment: yes. `config/routes.rb` I just added a link to a reasonable intro to this stuff.

Comment: Should I add a new "voting" method in the controller, or modify the update method?

Comment: added a controller example

Comment: Sweet. I think it should be working. But still getting a routing error when I go to /posts/1/upvote in the browser by clicking the upvote link: `Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/posts/1/upvote"` even though the two routes show up in `rake routes`

Comment: do you have `:method => "put"` in your `link_to` helper? It is trying to do a `GET` request ("put" may be a symbol :put, I don't remember)

Comment: I have `:method => "put"` and the HTML is processed with a `data-method="put"` attribute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22490/discussion-between-pferdefleisch-and-jackson-gariety)